# Add timestamp to tee'd output, but not original output

Tags: bash, tee

I'm writing a little budget script to keep an eye on my finances. I'd like to keep a log of all of my transactions and when they happened.

Currently, I input spendings as an argument:

```
f)
    echo "$OPTARG spent on food" | tee spendinglogs.log
    ... # take away money from monthly budget
    echo "$REMAINING_FOOD_BUDGET remaining" | tee spendinglogs.log

m)
    echo "$OPTARG spent on miscellaneous" | tee spendinglogs.log
    ... # take away money from monthly budget
    echo "$REMAINING_MISC_BUDGET remaining" | tee spendinglogs.log

... #etc
```

I don't want to timestamp output to the terminal, but I do want to timestamp output to the logs. Is there a way to do this?

For example

```
echo "$OPTARG spent on food" | tee `date %d-%m-%y %H_%M_%S` spendinglogs.log
```

But I can't imagine that working.

Answer (score 20):

EDIT: Tested and updated with correct info

Check out `ts` from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

If you're using `bash`, you can `tee` to a shell pipe as a file:

```
echo "$OPTARG spent on food" | tee >(ts "%d-%m-%y %H_%M_%S" > spendinglogs.log)
```

---

My previous answer correctly stated the above, correct answer, but also an incorrect one using `pee`, also from `moreutils`. `pee` appears to buffer stdin before sending it to the output pipes, so this will not work with timestamping (it will work with commands where the timing is not important however).

Comment: `ts` is a good utility. So far, I was only using `awk` for time-stamping. +1

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo something 2>&1 | while read line; do echo $line; echo "$(date) $line" >> something.log; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function tee_with_timestamps () {
    local logfile=$1
    while read data; do
        echo "${data}" | sed -e "s/^/$(date '+%T') /" >> "${logfile}"
        echo "${data}"
    done
}

echo "test" | tee_with_timestamps "file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet is prepending timestamp in front of each line in the log file.
The console output is without any timestamp.

```
exec &> >(tee -a >(sed "s/^/$(date) /" >> "${filename.log}"))
```

&> : for both stdout and stderr

>> : for appending in a file